tinymce 7 clear any html tag inside template tag
I just update my web from tinymce 4 to tinymce 7 and somehow tinymce now always cleanup everything inside <template></template>, anyone knows why?
I want tinymce allow to write inside <template></template> just like before in tinymce 4
